# C++: read/write binary files. What's happening in this code?

Tags: c++, casting, io, binaryfiles

I've been struggling with the concept of unformatted I/O. My course textbook doesn't explain it well. It gives the small program but I don't know what is happening here. If someone could explain it to me, I would appreciate it

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
     const unsigned int size = 10;
     int arr[size];
     ifstream infile("small.ppm");
     infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&arr), size * sizeof(arr[0]));
     infile.close();

     ofstream outfile("newfile.ppm");
     outfile.write((char *)&arr, size * sizeof(arr[0]));
     outfile.close();
    }
```

What do the read() and write() functions do exactly. I understand that they must
take in (char *, buffer_size) as arguments, but what do the functions themselves do?
Also, once I read in the data with read(), how do I store that data and manipulate it?

Sorry that this is such a long question. I've been struggling with this concept for a while now. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp <= documentation. Please read before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

> but what do the functions themselves do?

These are writing/reading the data as a byte by byte copy to/from the binary file.

> Also, once I read in the data with read(), how do I store that data and manipulate it?

You already stored a `int arr[size];`. You can manipulate that data using that `int` array.

**Pitfalls:**

If that data was serialized on a different machine, you'll notice endianess issues regarding the machine specific `int` representation.